# Getting the scrollbar height of a browser

Tags: javascript

Is their any javascript code to get the scroll height. I mean the scroll bar is how far from the top.
Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Answer is already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

it will work in both IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

use the scrollTop attribute. for example, the distance of the body's scrollbar from the top can be accessed at:

```
document.body.scrollTop;
```