# How do I make a div follow me as I scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

The user enters the site.

At this point, the div is in the middle of the page.

As he scrolls down the page, the div first begins to move upward, but once it hits the top, it stays there.

As he scrolls further down the page, the div stays near the top, always visible to the user.

As he scrolls up the page all the way to the top, the div once again stays back in position where it was originally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can hook the `scroll` event on the `window` object. When processing the event, look at the vertical scroll position of the window/document (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window/872537#872537) on SO for how to do that). Use absolute positioning for your `div` and update its `top` as coordinate as necessary.

FWIW, I would be very careful doing this. Usually when a user scrolls, it's because they want to look at different content than what's on the page. Personally, I hate boxes that follow me around on web pages. :-) But that doesn't mean there isn't a good reason for doing this on occasion.

Very basic example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/iwegec)):

```js
// Make sure this is in a script tag at the end of the body,
// just prior to the closing </body> tag.

function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== "undefined" ) {
        // Most browsers
        return window.pageYOffset;
    }
  
    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (typeof d.clientHeight !== "undefined") {
        // IE in standards mode
        return d.scrollTop;
    }
  
    // IE in quirks mode
    return document.body.scrollTop;
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  var scroll = getScrollTop();

  if (scroll <= 28) {
      box.style.top = "30px";
  } else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 2) + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
#box {
  /* Position absolutely, 30px down from the top */
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;

  /* In my case I'm centering it in the window; do what you like */
  margin-left: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;

  /* These are just for my example */
  height: 1.25em;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>I'm the box</div>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

(In my case, I'm always keeping it 2 pixels below the top, but if you don't want that you can adjust the numbers accordingly.)

Comment: Is there a way to make the box stop following the scroll at a certain point?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Sure, just limit the value of `scroll` in the `onscroll` handler.

Comment: I tried to make it stop scrolling at 900 pixels, and it seems to work when I add this code to the onscroll handler:     if(scroll > 500){
        scroll = 500;
}

Answer (score 0):

As you can see other people provided ready scripts, but if you want to make one your self (waste of time) [or you may want to learn].. here is a good point to start:

```
var hscroll = (document.all ? document.scrollLeft : window.pageXOffset);
var vscroll = (document.all ? document.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a lot simpler and might work just as good for some. Position: Fixed or Position: Sticky could do the job.

```
   <div class="col" style="position:fixed; top: 250px; left: 50%">

       <p>this box follows me while scrolling down</p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/25rgq/

This is an old implementation of your desired functionality, which I've used. It's one of the first scripts I wrote, so JS & jQuery knowing people will most likely vomit. I wrote it mainly due all the examples I found online were centered on moving the DIV rather than setting it to fixed, and incrementally adding to the top-margin of the box resulted in really choppy movement.

Basicly it changes to fixed as the specified element is a custom set margin from the top of the browser window, and stops moving down once it hits a custom offset before our footer (we wanted to constrain the followbox to not move past our sidebar space).

Hope it is of any use, and if a plugin to handle this nowadays exists, you would probably be better of using it.

Comment: Except for the fact that an expert implementation, perhaps released as a plugin would be both more optimized and less error prone, and easier to hook up into different types of web sites :)