# Image / Logo that scrolls down when the User scrolls?

Tags: html, css, image, scroll

I dont know how to phrase this question correctly, I would like to create something like the logo on the upper right corner of this website: http://www.afterthecircle.com/

When the user scrolls down, the logo moves with the scrolling movement and always stays visible to the user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're looking for fixed positioning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691558/how-do-i-make-a-div-follow-me-as-i-scroll-down-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) will allow you to scroll and keep an item in it's original position.

```
#fixed-thing {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GJZTx/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: fixed` along with top or bottom and left or right:

```
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As brbcoding said, you are looking for the CSS property position with the value fixed. With the properties top, bottom, left, and right, you can then position the element. An example:

CSS

```
.fixedElement {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class=fixedElement>Hey!</div>
```