# infinite scroll hide first elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using a infinite scroll and I would like hide content (50 first div elements) when user loaded 300 elements...

Example : user is currently on 250 - 290 element with scroll 
My goal : hide 0 - 50 element part

I tried to understand this algo from Mutahhir but there is a lack of code.

[Performance with infinite scroll or a lot of dom elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613113/performance-with-infinite-scroll-or-a-lot-of-dom-elements)

Thx

Comment: can't you just use JS to do that ?

Comment: you can use jquery hide() to make your elements display as 'none' http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

Try this css on your elements:

```
.yourelement:nth-child(-n+50){
    display:none;
}
```

I think you can set the .yourelement name in the itemSelector property of the plugin.