# How do I get dynamic content in a div while scrolling and still keep a limit on the number of nodes in the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I attempted to test the limit of my browser's DOM capability with the following code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="million"></div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            var t;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  h=$("#million").html();
                  for(i=1;i<1000000;i++){
                        h+='<span id="sp'+i+'" class="spC">'+i+'</span><br/>';
                  }
                  $("#million").html(h);
                  $(".spC").mouseover(function(e){
                        $(e.target).css('background','#C00');
                  });
                  $(".spC").mouseout(function(e){
                        $(e.target).css('background','#CC0');
                  });
            });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, the browser crashed. I am looking for a solution to dynamically load content in a `div`, but also limit the size of the DOM. This would be similar to facebook / Google+. However, I would also have to get rid of the nodes that have scrolled out of view.

It would also be great if I did not have to do another ajax if the user scrolled up again. Is there a framework that implements this feature? What approach should I take to implement this myself?

I considered something like -

```
  <div id="million">
        <div id="top_1_3"></div>
        <div id="mid_1_3"></div>
        <div id="bottom_1_3"></div>
  </div>
```

and move the contents -

while scrolling down:

> buffer_top <- top <- mid <- bottom <- buffer_bottom <- AJAX

while scrolling up:

> buffer_bottom <- bottom <- mid <- top <- buffer_top

And I have to adjust the scroll position so that the transition does not look jittery. And handle the case where the data is so little that there is no scroll bar to generate the scroll event. Is there any flaw in this? While handling 100,000 kind of records?

Comment: with `for(i=1;i<1000000;i++){` you will get 999 999 spans

Comment: Are you expexting the user to scroll so low down they'd get to browser-crashing amounts of elements? I don't think so. You'll be fine with just loading a smaller amount of data as the user scrolls.

Comment: Yes. A MATLAB habit. 999,999 or 100K all the same when the browser crashes.