# jQuery :first and .first() behaving differently in Chrome/Safari and FireFox/IE8

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to validate a form, on submit I want to scroll to the first instance of the class `.inputError` which I have set up like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input').each(function(){
        inputCheck.call(this);
    });
    errors = $('input.inputError').length;
    if (errors > 0) {
        $('body').scrollTop($('.inputError').first().offset().top-30);
    } else {
        submitForm();
    }
});
```

This works fine in Chrome/Safari, but in FireFox and IE8 it goes to the **last** instance of the class `.inputError` instead of the first. I have tried using `$('.inputError:first)` and `.first()` both produce the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first guess would be malformed html. If you miss some closingtag somewhere that's (in my experience) the most likely reason for browsers to behave differently.

Comment: Try using `$('body, html').scrollTop(...`

Comment: @adeneo thank you for the suggestion, that did the trick! If you would like to add your comment as the answer, I will gladly accept. Thanks again!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Are you *sure* that its selecting the last instance? There's nothing in your demo code to illustrate this. IE8 might just be struggling with the offset()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using

```
$('body, html').scrollTop(...
```

or alternatively

```
$(window).scrollTop(...
```

if the scrollbar is global, as the scrollbar belongs to different elements in different browsers.

Here are a few plain JS solutions as well, if someone should need that in the future ->
[Cross-browser method for detecting the scrollTop of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window)