# How to move svg chart on mouse scroll with D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scroll

I have two charts; bar chart and word cloud.

I would like word cloud to move down as I scroll down. Any ideas/examples on how to achieve this with D3.js / JavaScript?

Here is my **[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/C1eXL62sdqnkr2JU2bmi?p=preview)** (You should launch the preview in separate window).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can control the positioning of a DOM element through a window event listener like this:

```
  window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunc.bind(this, document.getElementById("scroller")), false);

  function myFunc(div) {
      var scroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      div.style.top = (scroll / 10)+"px";
  };
```

So for every ten pixels the user scrolls, the `scroller` element will move one pixel.

http://jsfiddle.net/76vd9h3g/

Cross browser implementation of `scrollTop` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window)